# Fill 0s with mean values of previous and next in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, imputation

Fill the 0s with the following conditions:

1. If there is one 0 value, do a simple average between the data after and before the 0. In this scenario 0 is replaced by mean of A and B
2. If there are two consecutive 0s, fill the first missing value with data from previous period and doing a simple average between the data after and before the second 0. First 0 is replaced by A and second 0 by mean of A and B.
3. If there are 3 consecutive 0s, replace first and second 0 with A and 3rd by mean of A and B.
   Ticker is an identifier and would be common for every block(can be ignored). The entire table is 1000 rows long and in no case consecutive 0s would exceed 3. I am unable to manage scenario 2 and 3.

| ID | asset |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 34861000 |
| AA | 1607498 |
| AA | 0 |
| AA | 3530000000 |
| AA | 3333000000 |
| AA | 3179000000 |
| AA | 4053000000 |
| AA | 4520000000 |
| AB | 15250209 |
| AB | 0 |
| AB | 14691049 |
| AB | 0 |
| AB | 5044421 |
| CC | 5609212 |
| CC | 0 |
| CC | 0 |
| CC | 3673639 |
| CC | 132484747 |
| CC | 0 |
| CC | 0 |
| CC | 0 |
| CC | 141652646 |

[image]

Comment: Maybe `shift` 3 times and process each row like that?

Comment: And please provide [minimum reproduce example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added a table

Comment: You are looking for some customized linear interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) per group, on the reversed Series, with a limit of 1:

```
df['asset'] = (df
 .assign(asset=df['asset'].replace(0, float('nan')))
 .groupby('ID')['asset']
 .transform(lambda s: s[::-1].interpolate(limit=1).bfill())
)
```

output:

```
    ID         asset
0   AA  3.486100e+07
1   AA  1.607498e+06
2   AA  1.765804e+09
3   AA  3.530000e+09
4   AA  3.333000e+09
5   AA  3.179000e+09
6   AA  4.053000e+09
7   AA  4.520000e+09
8   AB  1.525021e+07
9   AB  1.497063e+07
10  AB  1.469105e+07
11  AB  9.867735e+06
12  AB  5.044421e+06
13  CC  5.609212e+06
14  CC  5.609212e+06
15  CC  4.318830e+06
16  CC  3.673639e+06
17  CC  1.324847e+08   # X
18  CC  1.324847e+08   # filled X
19  CC  1.324847e+08   # filled X
20  CC  1.393607e+08   # (X+Y)/2
21  CC  1.416526e+08   # Y
```

Comment: This is almost correct, but need to check the group by clause, as the mean values(X+Y)/2 are not correct when applying the solution. It is getting rolled up differently.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, compiling the answer here with help from @jezrael and @mozway

```
df['asset'] =df['asset'].replace(0, float('nan'))
df.loc[mask, 'asset'] = df.loc[mask | ~m, 'asset'].groupby(df['ID']).transform(lambda x: x.interpolate())
df.ffill()
```